# How to make a reference to an entity using the uuid of the entity?

Tags: 7, entities, features

Is there any way to make a reference to an entity (using refereces, entity reference or relation) using the uuid of the entity?

I'm using features and uuid_features to export the content but refereces are being exported using the id and not the uuid.

Comment: See http://drupal.org/node/1225198. I think it is being work on at the moment.